# Submitting form leads to blank page when jQuery validate plugin used

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate, fat-free-framework

I'm using jQuery validate plugin in my form.
Validation works fine except when I'm using this '**data**' function to send data.
When I comment out this **data** section, form is submitted and redirected properly and other validation is implemented properly.
But using **data** , form is submitted and redirected to blank page.

Validation for checking duplicate email in database is checked here.. With the following **data** function, validation is working but the submission is not working.

Here's my part of validation script:

```
personal_email: {
    email: true,
    remote: {
       param:{
           url: app.baseurl('user/check_personal_email'),
           type: 'POST',
           data: 
             {
               userID : function()
                     {
                      return $("#userID").val();
                     }
             }

            }
            // ,
            //  depends: function(element)
            //  {
            //      return ($('#editTrue').val() == undefined && $('#editTrue').val() == null);
            //  }
              }
            },
```

Controller function that handles and returns the above **url** request is :

```
public function checkPersonalEmailExists($f3)
{
    $userID = $f3->get('POST.userID');
    $email = $f3->get('POST.personal_email');
    $user = new UserModel();
    $records = $user->checkIfPersonalEmailExists($email);

    if(count($records) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($records as $record) 
        {
            $user_id = $record['id'];
        }
        echo ($userID == $user_id) ? 'true' : 'false';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

Here's my HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="user/save" id="employee-form">
    <input name="personal_email" type="email" class="form-control" id="personal_email">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update" value="update">Update User</button>
</form>
```

Form submission is handled by following function:

```
public function save($f3)
{
   $save = $f3->get('POST.save');
   $update = $f3->get('POST.update');

   if(isset($save) || isset($update))
     {
        echo 'It is working';
        // saving to database stuff...
        exit;
     }
   else
     {
        echo 'It is not working';
        exit;
     }
}
```

One thing I noticed is that when every elements are filled with valid data.. then only it is acting this way. Else, it is displaying 'It is working'.

It seems that with **data** in validation, **submit** button value is not recognized.. It displays 'It is not working'.

I cannot figure out what's wrong, and how jQuery validation plugin behaves.

Please help me with this. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This most likely means that the `data` property you've defined is causing an problem when validating. Check the console for errors. It's probably because you've defined `userID` as a function instead of a string value.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there're no errors.. also, the validation it is supposed to do is doing fine.. only the submission went rogue..

Comment: Unless you have the plugin's `submitHandler` setup with something, the jQuery Validate plugin does not do the "submit".  It's simply interrupts whatever submission mechanism you already have in place, and then allows it to continue when the form is valid.  You probably have some kind of JavaScript syntax error.  Show the rest of the relevant code from your `.validate()` call.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, he is supposed to use a function there.  See the docs:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: To the OP, you should also read the docs.  Look at the second example and remove `param{}`... it's not needed.  Just list your parameters within `remote{}` as shown:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: `remote` is looking for `user/check_personal_email`, but your function is named `checkPersonalEmailExists`.... spelling mistake?